# Set value of a variable inside an if statement. And use it outside the satement afterwards

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, twitch

So I've been trying to set a value for a variable when a user types something in chat that is en the linksDisallowed array. However I can't get the value of the variables outside the if statement. Can anyone please help me out?

The code looks as following:

```js
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  
  if(message.indexOf(linksDisallowed[i]) >= 0) {
    var timeoutUser = 1;
   //console.log("Link detected!");
   //client.say("dunkstormen", "Ahem! " + user.username + " are you allowed to post links?!");
  } else {
   var timeoutUser = 0;
   //console.log("No link detected!");
   //client.say("dunkstormen", "Hello, " + user.username);
  }
  
 }
 
 if(timeoutUser == 1) {
  console.log("Timing out " + user.username);
 } else {
  timeoutUser == 0
  console.log("Not timing out " + user.username);
 }
});
```

Comment: If you define your variable with `var` it is accessible inside the whole function (function scope). So therefore, you have access to `timeoutUser` after the `if` and `for`. There has to be some other mistake here.

Comment: You set the value of the variable in a loop, so after the loop it will hold whatever value was set in the final iteration. So effectively you're really only testing the third disallowed link value. Perhaps you want a `break` statement in your `if` to get out of the loop as soon as you have a match? (If so, set the variable to 0 before the loop and remove the else case.)

Answer (score 2):

The code you shown should work, because it doesn't matter where in the function the var is defined it's ok as var declarations are hoisted and the variable is scoped to the function level, not to the block level.

Something else causes your problem, not the declaration of the variable.

What you can do to make the code more readable is to declare the variable right at the entrance in the function:

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    var timeoutUser;
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        if(message.indexOf(linksDisallowed[i]) >= 0) {
             timeoutUser = 1;
            //console.log("Link detected!");
            //client.say("dunkstormen", "Ahem! " + user.username + " are you allowed to post links?!");
        } else {
            timeoutUser = 0;
            //console.log("No link detected!");
            //client.say("dunkstormen", "Hello, " + user.username);
        }

    }

    if(timeoutUser == 1) {
        console.log("Timing out " + user.username);
    } else {
        timeoutUser == 0
        console.log("Not timing out " + user.username);
    }
});
```

Comment: Found out that i forgot to break my for loop when it detected a link. So it would continue checking for the other strings in my array, and then put timeoutUser back to 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    var timeoutUser = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if(message.indexOf(linksDisallowed[i]) >= 0) {
            timeoutUser = 1;
            // console.log("Link detected!");
            // client.say("dunkstormen", "Ahem! " + user.username + " are you allowed to post links?!");
        } else {            
            // console.log("No link detected!");
            // client.say("dunkstormen", "Hello, " + user.username);
        }

    }

    if(timeoutUser == 1) {
        console.log("Timing out " + user.username);
    } else {
        console.log("Not timing out " + user.username);
    }
});
```

Comment: You are just posting some code and do not answer the question. By the change you made to the original code, one would assume that you corrected it and that it was wrong before. However, you only restructured the code which has no effect to the output. You need to describe what your goal was.

Comment: I have changed the variable location if u see carefully.

Comment: Moving the `var` statement to another spot in the same function won't help, because variables created with `var` already have function scope, *not* block scope.